# Implementation of the secant method for finding a root of a function

Tags: java, function, math, methods

I have written the following code as an implementation of the *secant method*. It happens to be in Java but is basically translatable to similar languages such as C++ (and C if you ignore the exceptions).

```
public interface Function
{
    public double f(double x);
};

public class Secant
{
    public static double find(Function f, double a, double b, double epsilon)
    {
        double fa = f.f(a), fb = f.f(b);

        if (fa == fb) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        double c = b - ((fb * (b - a)) / (fb - fa));

        if (Math.abs(c - b) > epsilon) return find(f, b, c, epsilon);
        else return c;
    }
};
```

In this code, (f) is a class implementing the **Function** interface, (a) is the previous approximation of the root, (b) is the current approximation of the root and (epsilon) is, as far as I understand it, the maximum difference between the two most recent approximations for the method to be finished. If I am correct in believing this, would not checking if |c-b| is greater than (epsilon) do the trick?

This seems to work fine for normal functions like *x^2 + 2x + 1* but a problem arises when I attempt to run *find* with a Function returning **Math.log(x)** - the root it finds is *NaN*.

Is there something wrong with my code or am I just not understanding the actual mathematics correctly? I'd appreciate if someone would shed some light on the matter.

Comment: Just curious is there a reason you chose recursion rather than just a while loop until the algorithm converges?

Comment: Doing this "catch (Exception e) { throw e; }" is useless; e is already being trown, you can remove the try block altogether.

Comment: Excuse me: `epsilon` is the _minimum_ difference? Wouldn't it be the _maximum_ difference?

Comment: The algorithm looks okay to me, although using recursion instead of a simple `while` loop is an odd decision. Do you have any particular issue with running this code?

Comment: @Little Santi Sorry, I meant the maximum tolerance.

Comment: @Normal Human I added a more specific explanation of the problem in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secant method is not guaranteed to converge. For example, the point c you get from the method may happen to be outside of the domain of your function. This is not an issue when f is defined everywhere (e.g., a polynomial), but the logarithm is defined only for positive values of the argument:

[image: log]

When the secant line is such that its intersection with the x-axis lies in the negative half, you end up calling `find(f,b,c,epsilon)` with negative b, and get NaN because of an attempt to take the logarithm of a negative number.

Possible remedies:

1. Throw an exception and tell the user to try again with different initial values.
2. Attempt to recover: if f(b) is undefined, replace b with (a+b)/2 (e.g., `return find(f, a, (a+b)/2, epsilon)`. This might help the algorithm recover, although on the other hand you may get stuck in an infinite loop (recursion in your case).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying, could you show me an example based on my previous code?

Comment: If you mean the second suggestion: it was add a catcher for exceptions when evaluating f.f(b). In the catcher, put `return find(f, a, (a+b)/2, epsilon)`  But I'm not saying this is what you need to do. **Your algorithm works fine**. The possible failure to find a root is inherent to the method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the described method, it may be non convergent. The simplest way is to start with 2 numbers a and b for which `f(a)` and `f(b)` have different sign. Provided f is continuous on `[a;b]` (assuming `a < b`)  the secant algorythm will then give `c` with `a < c < b`. In fact you do not keep the last guess, but the best one

You then iterate (or recurse with your implementation), with `a, c` if `f(c)` has same sign as `f(b)`, else with `c, b`.

Possible implementation :

```
public class Secant
{
    static double find(Function f, double a, double b, double epsilon)
    {
        double temp;
        if (b < a) {
             temp = a;
             a = b;
             b = temp;
        }
        double fa = f.f(a), fb = f.f(b);

        if (fa == fb) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        double c = b - ((fb * (b - a)) / (fb - fa));

        if (Math.abs(c - b) > epsilon) {
            if (f.f(a) * f.f(b) < 0) { // different signs for f(a) and f(b)
                if (f.f(a) * f.f(c) < 0) {
                    return find(f, a, c, epsilon);
                }
                else {
                    return find(f, c, b, epsilon);
                }
            }
            else { // same signs for f(a) and f(b)
                if (((f.f(a) < f.f(b)) && (f.f(c) < f.f(a))) || ((f.f(a) > f.f(b)) && (f.f(c) > f.f(a)))) {
                    // f(a) between f(b) and f(c)
                    return find(f, a, c, epsilon);
                }
                else {
                    return find(f, c, b, epsilon);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return c;
        }
    }
};
```

For a continuous function, this implementation is guaranteed to converge as soon as you find 2 numbers (at one recursion level) for which `f(a) * f(b) < 0`

If you cannot get easily 2 numbers for which `f(a) * f(b) < 0`, this method should only be used when you are already in a neibourhood of the root and the tangents on both points, the secant and the function itself are all near enough. In fact (except that it does not need any knowledge of the derivative function) it should only be used where Euler method can be. So the normal use case is :

- first use dichotomy to find a neighbourhood of a root because it is a robust method even if it converges slowly
- next use Euler or secant method to quickly gain precision on root value because they converge more quickly but are far lest robust.

Comment: Ignoring the syntactic errors, using this code leads to far more errors than the one I wrote.

Comment: @SulDoher: An iterative method would be far more robust, but given a = 0.1, and b = 10.0, epsilon = 1e-10, it gives 1.0 in 95 iterations for Math.log(x), 3 in 17 iterations for x^2 -4x+3. But the problem is that secant method should only be used in a neighborhood of a root. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Secant method of determining the roots of a polynomial.  */

import java.util.*;

public class Secant {

private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private static List<Double> coefficients = new ArrayList<>();

/**
 * Enter the order and coefficients of the function. If coefficient doesn't
 * exist, enter 0.
 */
private static void inputFunction() {
    System.out.print("Enter the order of the polynomial: ");
    int order = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the coefficient of terms of the function: ");

    while (order >= 0) {
        double value = input.nextDouble();
        coefficients.add(value);
        order--;
    }
}

/**
 * The function method to compute the value of the function given variable x
 * 
 * @param x
 * @return result of inputing variable x
 */
private static double function(double x) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (int index = 0, order = coefficients.size()-1; index < coefficients.size(); order--, index++) {
        result += coefficients.get(index) * (Math.pow(x, order));
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    inputFunction();
    
    double xn1; // This represent x_n-1
    double xn, x, precision;

    System.out.print("Enter the start of the interval: ");
    xn1 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the end of the interval: ");
    xn = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the precision of the interval (e.g 0.000001): ");
    precision = input.nextDouble();

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    if (function(xn1) * function(xn) > 0.0) {
        System.out.println("Functions result have same sign value ...");
        //return;
    }

    x = xn1;
    int iterations = 0;
    while (Math.abs(function(x)) > precision) {
        
        System.out.println("x" + iterations + ": " + x + " f(x"+ iterations + "): " + function(x));
        
        x = xn - (function(xn) * (xn-xn1))/(function(xn) - function(xn1));
        xn1 = xn;
        xn = x;
        iterations++;
    }
    
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timeUsed = (stopTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("The root of the equation is " +
                Math.round(x*1000000)/1000000.0);       // Answer is rounded to 6 decimal places.
    System.out.println("Time used is " + timeUsed + " milliseconds.");
}
}
```

Comment: This code solves a polynomial of n-order. The coefficient of each term is entered and stored in an ArrayList, while the initial points are entered as xn & xn1. Your initial points should be such that the root converges.